# Facebook Graph API return only one page of Inbox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, inbox

I tried accessing the facebook inbox using the graph API's `https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox?limit=0&access_token=<extended_access_token>`
This returns few recent messages of the inbox without access to previous messages. There is no paging for inbox. Also, I couldn't find any documentation related to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Is the API designed to be this way?

Comment: When using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) i can see all of my inbox messages.  The API should work the same way.

Comment: I added limit=0. It returns some more messages, but not the whole inbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the until parameter for pagination of your inbox.

`/me/threads?until=2011-05-01`

The new inbox is now called threads rather than inbox.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/ (yes in the Graph API Explorer it is plural rather than what the documentation shows as singular)

Comment: On the docs.. """The user must be a tester, developer, or admin of the app making the request.""". :(... is not very useful.

Comment: Not very useful for what exactly? Facebook says: "This endpoint is only accessible for users that are developers of the app making the request.". This endpoint achieves this goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can set any limit you want by adding ?limit=Amount on the request.

Example:

```
FB.api('/me/threads/?limit=50', function(response){ 
   console.log(response);
});
```